# React hook form how can multiple forms register to multiple form contexts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-hook-form

I'm trying to build a sort of multi step form with React Hook Form, but it is not the classic multi step form. In my case I need to persist in the database on every submit.

To me that was an indication that I should split the form into small forms, and validate each one of them individually.

The only problem - but not simple - with this approach is that now I'm running into situations where **one step needs data from another step**. Since each individual form has its own `FormProvider`, I can only use `useContext` to access data from their correspondent context. I don't want to build another context just to store all data from all steps.

This is an ilustration of the structure I currently have

```
interface IForm1 {
    id?: number;
}

interface IForm2 {
    name?: string;
}

const GenericForm = <T extends FieldValues, >(props: PropsWithChildren<T>) => {
    const form = useForm<T>();

    return <FormProvider {...form}>
        <form>
            {props.children}
        </form>
    </FormProvider>;
};

const MyForms = () => <>
    <GenericForm<IForm1>>
        <Component1 />
    </GenericForm>
    <GenericForm<IForm2>>
        <Component1 />
    </GenericForm>
</>;
```

Now I want the children components to be able to access data from both contexts, something like this:

```
const Component1 = () => {
    const { watch } = useFormContext<IForm1>();
    const form2Context = useFormContext<IForm2>();

    const id = watch('id');
    const name = form2Context.watch('name');

    return <div>
        {id}
        and
        {name}
    </div>;
};
```

This won't work since each FormProvider is in a different level, so I thought of doing something like this:

```
const MyForms = () => <>
    <FormProvider {...form1}>
        <FormProvider {...form2}>
            <GenericForm<IForm1>>
                <Component1 />
            </GenericForm>
            <GenericForm<IForm2>>
                <Component1 />
            </GenericForm>
        </FormProvider>
</>;
```

This also didn't work, the deepest FormProvider seems to override all parents.

Has anyone ever had this kind of problem? Any ideas?

Another idea that I'm investigating would be to try to expose the form methods - `watch` `setValue` to the parent and register them somehow in an Record. This way any child could use them. The problem is that it is really hard to keep these methods in sync.

**Update**

I found a way to combine the instances of useForm()

```
It is something like this:

    const form1 = useForm();
    const form2 = useForm();
    
    
    <FormProvider {...{ ...form1, ...form2}}>
       <form>Form 1</form>
       <form>Form 2</form>
    </FormProvider>
```

The problem is that when I try to use `useFormContext` I can see that the context contains a large object with all the properties of the two forms as if like they were simply combined.

I thought the contexts would be separated from each other and that I could do something like:

```
const form1 = useFormContext<IForm1>();
```

This does not work =/

Comment: Could you explain the difference in forms in this case? 
I have a large form 100+ fields in different steps. I just use keys for the steps, and add on the prefix to the fields names. 
Extra tip the watch function is not that good for performance, the useWatch hook is a bit better if you want to "subscribe" to specific fields

Comment: @Disco the difference is that I really need to be able to submit the data from each form separatelly. This means I have a different instance of useForm() for each form. Ideally I'd have a context containing data from all instances of useForm(). Does that make sense? Thanks for the tip regarding the useWatch hook, I'll consider using it.

Comment: I do not use `submit` in my forms. You can just use a regular button, trigger validation manually and get the values of the subform and do the same that you would on submit.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a state library. Because sometimes When the forms start to get complicated, it can be a pain to use `React Context` to manage those forms.

The state management library I have used is [@legendapp/state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@legendapp/state).

It is easy to use and is performant in most cases.

But if you want to stick with react context; the only possible solution is to use one form provider with different objects for each form.

like the state object would be like:

```
{
form1: {data},
form2: {data},
form3: {data}
}
```

then in each sub-form, use a `useEffect` and `useWatch` to update the data in your context.

Comment: Yeah... that's kind of the way I'm doing it right now. I use Mobx to do something similar. The only problem is that I find it a bit risky to be out of sync from formState with this approach.

Comment: Yeah, I think at the moment, it's okay to do it this way as long as you update on each change of useWatch. When I run into these issues of syncing states, I just update the states when there's an onBlur action to make sure it's all updated.

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Got a good Idea, and here is a simple way you could do this dynamically

First you will have this

```js
<FormProvider {form1, form2}}>
  <Form> contextKey="form1">Form 1 </Form>
  <Form> contextKey="form1">Form 2 </Form>
</FormProvider>
// and then use your Form
const Form = ({contextKey, children}:{contextKey: string,children: any}) => {
    const form = (useContext() as any)[contextKey];
    // and now based on the contextKey you will be able to get the right form.
    return (
        <form>
            {children}
        </form>
        )
};
```

You will have to use `state` and `useEffect` to watch the changes.

Let me know what you think